# Does a division on a numerator have to be applied toward a denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm a bit weak on this stuff but if I wanted to get 
$\dfrac{-.5+z^{-1}}{1-.9z^{-1}}$ into $\dfrac{\frac{1 - z^{-1}}{.5}}{1-.9z^{-1}}$ 
could I just divide the numerator by $-.5$ to get 
$\dfrac{\frac{1 - z^{-1}}{.5}}{1-.9z^{-1}}$?

Or would I have to apply the division to the denominator as well?

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply it to the denominator as well or else it will become something entirely different.

You're basically multiplying by $\frac{-\frac{1}{0.5}}{-\frac{1}{0.5}}=1$

Comment: Is there a way to keep the denominator the same but change the numerator into that form?

Answer (score 2):

If you want them to be equal, you have to apply the same operations to both numerator and denominator.